# Round to two digits after decimal place without any package.

Tags: tables, formatting

I have the following table. I need to format it so that the figures displayed are rounded to two digits after decimal place. I searched and all the solutions I found involve the use of a Latex package. I can't use a package (I think?) because I'm working with ShareLatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbp] \centering%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\caption{Differences}%
{\normalsize
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lCCCC}
\toprule
Economy&year&nef\_en&gdi\_wer&inf\\\tabularnewline
\midrule\addlinespace[1.5ex]
Belize&2006&4.240267&-7.113768&-11.35403 \tabularnewline
Central African Republic&2014&8.2&25.28281&17.08281 \tabularnewline
Iran, Islamic Rep.&2012&30.5&27.35739&-3.142611 \tabularnewline
Iran, Islamic Rep.&2013&34.78927&39.26636&4.477088 \tabularnewline
Iceland&2009&16.27129&12.00581&-4.265474 \tabularnewline
Kenya&2006&6&14.45373&8.453734 \tabularnewline
Kenya&2007&4.3&9.758881&5.45888 \tabularnewline
Kenya&2008&16.2&26.23982&10.03982 \tabularnewline
Kuwait&2008&6.3&10.58271&4.28271 \tabularnewline
Myanmar&2013&8.876498&5.524279&-3.352219 \tabularnewline
Mongolia&2007&17.70245&9.045246&-8.657202 \tabularnewline
Mongolia&2013&12.5&8.604828&-3.895172 \tabularnewline
Mongolia&2015&1.9&5.775949&3.87595 \tabularnewline
Chad&2011&2.040816&-3.704296&-5.745112 \tabularnewline
Chad&2012&7.512763&14.01821&6.505443 \tabularnewline
\bottomrule \addlinespace[1.5ex]
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Why don't you want to use a package? The only reason I know for wanting this is usually that the question is homework. Otherwise it seems weird.

Comment: I don't have admin rights, so I can't install any Latex system on my computer. That's why I'm using ShareLatex. All I'm doing is using Stata to generate Latex code so that I can then paste it on an email message.

Comment: What does that have to do with not using packages? You are using ShareLaTeX: you have access to packages. What's the problem?

Comment: I was not aware of that. I presumed Latex packages where like R or Stata libraries where one downloads them before running code that calls each package. Can you point in the right direction on how to use a package to solve my inquiry?

Comment: You're already using several packages: `booktabs`, `tabularx` and `array` at least. (`tabularx` loads `array`.) Werner has answered your specific query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ShareLaTeX should be installed with a complete distribution. The following works and uses [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) to round columns 3-5 to two decimal places (the default value for `round-precision`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Differences}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X c *{3}{S[round-mode = places]} }
    \toprule
    Economy & year & {nef\_en} & {gdi\_wer} & {inf} \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace[1.5ex]
    Belize                   & 2006 &  4.240267 & -7.113768 & -11.35403  \\
    Central African Republic & 2014 &  8.2      & 25.28281  &  17.08281  \\
    Iran, Islamic Rep.       & 2012 & 30.5      & 27.35739  &  -3.142611 \\
    Iran, Islamic Rep.       & 2013 & 34.78927  & 39.26636  &   4.477088 \\
    Iceland                  & 2009 & 16.27129  & 12.00581  &  -4.265474 \\
    Kenya                    & 2006 &  6        & 14.45373  &   8.453734 \\
    Kenya                    & 2007 &  4.3      &  9.758881 &   5.45888  \\
    Kenya                    & 2008 & 16.2      & 26.23982  &  10.03982  \\
    Kuwait                   & 2008 &  6.3      & 10.58271  &   4.28271  \\
    Myanmar                  & 2013 &  8.876498 &  5.524279 &  -3.352219 \\
    Mongolia                 & 2007 & 17.70245  &  9.045246 &  -8.657202 \\
    Mongolia                 & 2013 & 12.5      &  8.604828 &  -3.895172 \\
    Mongolia                 & 2015 &  1.9      &  5.775949 &   3.87595  \\
    Chad                     & 2011 &  2.040816 & -3.704296 &  -5.745112 \\
    Chad                     & 2012 &  7.512763 & 14.01821  &   6.505443 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```